# Swift, EXC_BAD_Instruction

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, word-wrap

My program should fitch the data from an array, and put it in a tableView

```
 var rideTime: String!
    var rideLocation: String!
    var RideDriver: String!

    rideTime = RidestList[indexPath.row].TimeX!
    rideLocation = RidestList[indexPath.row].LocationX!
    RideDriver = RidestList[indexPath.row].DriverNameX!


    cell.DriverX.text = rideTime;
    cell.TimeX.text = rideLocation;
    cell.LocationX.text = RideDriver;

    return cell
```

In the cell.DriverX.text=rideTime it gives me EXC_BAD_Instraction

And a "atal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb) " error appears, can anyone help?

Comment: Too many exclamation marks. Any exclamation mark is an invitation: *please crash me*. Or the outlet is not connected. Or the current instance is not the instance designed in Interface Builder.

Comment: Check outlet of  DriverX control.

Comment: Your `rideTime` var is probably nil. Maybe `RidestList` does not contain a value at location `indexPath.row`? Try adding a breakpoint and step through your code line by line. When you have isolated the error, have a look at optionals to make your code less error prone.

Comment: Don't use to much force unwrap paradigm. instead use guard and if..let statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if let ride_time = RidestList[indexPath.row].TimeX
    {
       cell.DriverX.text = ride_time
    } 

 if let ride_location =RidestList[indexPath.row].LocationX 
    {

       cell.TimeX.text = ride_location
}

 if let river_driver =RidestList[indexPath.row].DriverNameX
    {

       cell.LocationX.text = river_driver
}
```

this could help you with your problem

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The crash is basically due to no value coming to your variable **rideTime**. Best practice is use of optional binding **var rideTime: String?** to the variables which can expect null values. This will restrict the crash that you faced.

Comment: *Best practice is* to declare the string variables as non-optional, this will avoid this kind of crash at all.